# How to switch screens using tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to switch the screen using the tkinter module.

Is it possible to switch screens without frame?

This is the code I did.

```
#frame1.py
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
root.title('page1')

def goto_p2():
    root.destroy()
    import frame2
Button(root, text="goto page1", command=goto_p2).pack()

mainloop()
```

.

```
#frame2.py
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
root.title('page1')

def goto_p1():
    root.destroy()
    import frame1
Button(root, text="goto page2", command=goto_p1).pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: What is the reason of not using frames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, example code how it can be done.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Button,Label


def clear_frame():
    for widget in window.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()


def screen_two():
    clear_frame()
    button_2 = Button(window, text="Go to  screen one", command=lambda: screen_one())
    button_2.pack(pady=10)
    label_2 = Label(window, text="Label on window two")
    label_2.pack(pady=10)


def screen_one():
    clear_frame()
    button_1 = Button(window, text="Go to screen two", command=lambda: screen_two())
    button_1.pack(pady=10)
    label_1 = Label(window, text="Label on window one")
    label_1.pack(pady=10)


window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Test")
window.geometry('250x100')

screen_one()
window.mainloop()
```

[EDITED]

Function  `clear_frame()` will destroy every widget in frame ( basicly it will clear screen). Besides `clear_frame()`, there are two more functions, `screen_two()` and `screen_one()`. Both of those functions are doing the same thing, calling `clear_frame()` function, and displaying one button and one label. (Only difference is text inside label and text inside button).
When code runs, it will create `window` with `geometry` of `250x100`. It will call `screen_one()` function and run `mainloop()`.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/360251/edit) your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.